# How can I find the straight line approximation for the shape boundary?

Tags: opencv, graphics

This is the image :

[image]

I need to find the straight line approximation for the boundary of this image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. threshold
2. findContours
3. approxPolyDP

---

```
#findContours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

canvas = img.copy()

## draw approx contours

for cnt in contours:
    arclen = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, arclen*0.005, True)
    #drawContours
    cv2.drawContours(canvas, [approx], -1, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite("result.png", canvas)
```

---

[image]